# How to send several fields in the response with a PUT request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like when my PUT request is successful it returns me a response with all the fields in my `PlantSerializer` because currently the response returns me this:

```
{
   "id":48,
   "name":"Jar",
   "width":"50",
   "height":"50",
   "exposure":"None",
   "qr_code":"",
   "garden":65,
   "plant":[
      7
   ]
}
```

But, I would like the response to return this instead:

```
{
   "id":48,
   "name":"Jar",
   "width":"50",
   "height":"50",
   "exposure":"None",
   "qr_code":"",
   "garden":65,
   "plant":[
      "id":7,
      "name":"Artichoke",
      "image":null
   ]
}
```

How can I achieve this result?

Here is my serializers and my model class :

```js
class Plot(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    garden = models.ForeignKey('perma_gardens.Garden', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    plant = models.ManyToManyField('perma_plants.Plant', related_name='%(class)s_plant', blank=True)

# Here is my serializers :
class GardenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Garden
        fields = ('id', 'name',)

class PlantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Plant
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image')


class ReadPlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    garden = GardenSerializer(required=True)
    plant = PlantSerializer(many=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plot
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = [fields]


class WritePlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Plot
        fields = '__all__'
```

And here is my views :

```js
class PlotViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Plot.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = WritePlotSerializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        serializer = WritePlotSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ("list", "retrieve"):
            return ReadPlotSerializer
        return WritePlotSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fuction `partial_update` you are utilizing the `WritePlotSerializer`, which only has the `plant` field implicitly through the `fields=__all__` value. This is probably causing drf to use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, and as such you don't get all the extra fields you defined in your `PlantSerializer`.

If I understand correctyl you want to use the `WritePlotSerializer` in the update but use the `ReadPlotSerializer` when returning the object. You probably should combine both of them in a single serializer by overriding the `update` method in order to support updating the nested `Plant` objects. Here is the [related documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Alternatively, if you don't want to update the `Plants` values you can use a slightly modified version of the `ReadPlotSerializer` in all calls:

```
class PlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    garden = GardenSerializer(required=True, read_only=True)
    plant = PlantSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plot
        fields = '__all__'
```